# Disallow Bean Definition Overriding?

Tags: spring-boot

I want to disallow bean definition overriding in a `SpringApplication`. In other words, I want the effect of invoking `GenericApplicationContext.setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding(false)`. Is there a recommended way for doing that in Spring Boot?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 7):

Well, you can achieve it with some Boot features and context customization:

```java
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MyApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new SpringApplicationBuilder(MyApp.class)
                .initializers(new ApplicationContextInitializer<GenericApplicationContext>() {
                    @Override
                    public void initialize(GenericApplicationContext applicationContext) {
                        applicationContext.setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding(false);
                    }
                }).run(args);
    }

}
```

All other info you can find from source code and JavaDocs of mentioned classes.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across similar issue but not in spring boot application but in normal spring-mvc application which is having xml based configurations, so this solution might help people looking for other than spring-boot apps,

```
DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory = new DefaultListableBeanFactory();
    beanFactory.setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding(false);
    new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(beanFactory).loadBeanDefinitions(new ClassPathResource("spring-first.xml"));
```