# How to avoid circular reference while using Spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to disallow circular reference by default when using Spring boot. Unfortunately I cannot find a way to set the property `GenericApplicationContext.setAllowCircularReferences(false)` which I believe will make spring throw an exception when there is a circular reference in the code.

Any idea how I can bootstrap my application to disallow circular references? I am using `SpringApplication.run()` to bootstrap spring.

Comment: How about the answer at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312575/disallow-bean-definition-overriding?

Comment: That actually worked! Thanks!